# How can I get these two jQuery scripts to work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, lightbox

One is an audio player for Mp3s, and the other is a Lightbox I'm trying to display YouTube videos in.

Here's the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/videobox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="videobox/css/videobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/styles.css" />
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.ubaplayer.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){
            $("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
            codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}]
            });
        });
</script>
```

I've noticed that the lightbox works when I remove "libs/jquery/jquery.js" but then my audio player stops working.

I'm not very skilled when it comes to Javascript/JQuery, so the answer might be obvious.

**UPDATE:**

This fixed the problem!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="videobox/js/videobox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="videobox/css/videobox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/css/styles.css" />
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.ubaplayer.js"></script>
<script>
   jQuery.noConflict();
   jQuery(function(){
            jQuery("#ubaPlayer").ubaPlayer({
            codecs: [{name:"MP3", codec: 'audio/mpeg;'}]
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: There is a conflict in your page. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+mootools

Comment: try replace $ with jQuery, and put jQuery.noConflict() before

Comment: Where do I put jQuery.noConflict()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both MooTools and jQuery uses the `$` variable, that means you can't use them both. 2 solutions:

1. Search for jQuery/MooTools implementations of both features, I'm sure you will find those.
2. Use [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict) to let MooTools use the `$` variable.
3. Use the `jQuery` variable instead of `$` and include MooTools **after** jQuery. If you want to use the `$` shortcut for jQuery, wrap your jQuery code in a domready event with the `$` as parameter of the callback:

   ```
   jQuery(function($) {
       // ... jQuery code ($ has a copy of `jQuery` now)
   });
   // ... MooTools code ($ has a reference to the `MooTools.id` method now)
   ```

Comment: Can you explain number 3 a little simpler? What do you mean by "use the jQuery variable instead of $?"

Comment: @user2150204 I recommend you to use one of the other 2 solutions, but the answer: jQuery is officially saved in the `jQuery` variable, but it has an easy short cut in the `$` variable. If the `$` variable is changed to MooTools, you can still use the `jQuery` variable (since both variables have a copy of the jQuery framework).

Comment: So, if I go with number 2, where do I input jQuery.noConflict?

Comment: @user2150204 have you actually read the answers given on the duplicate I linked to??  And, 1 is really the best one, just find the jQuery implementation, there are a lot of those plugins. Loading 2 libraries is just much to big for just 2 features.

Comment: Well, for now number 2 fixed the problem, but I couldn't really understand how I would merge the two libraries. Are they essentially the same?

Comment: @user2150204 merging? They do somewhat the same thing, just search for *jquery lightbox*, find the plugin you want and remove all MooTools and VideoBox stuff and use that plugin together with ubaPlayer.

Comment: Ohh... I see what you're saying. I tried other ones, but never could get them to work properly. I'm not sure why. I tried Colorbox, Fancybox, and a couple of others. None of them worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can isolate your jQuery code inside of an autoexecuting function passing the jQuery object as argument. So that $ means inside of the scope jQuery but outside it can be something else.

```
(function ($) {

    // your jQuery code here

}(jQuery));
```

It is very common to pass also the object window to avoid resolving the global scope, and receive window and undefined. Since you only pass 2 arguments, the 3rd must be undefined, which improves compressibility of the code and makes more stable (undefined can be unfortunately redefined)

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {

    // your jQuery code here

}(jQuery, window));
```